# CROSS JOIN DATA inside a INNER JOIN (select ) problem of multi-part

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to use the "CROSS JOIN" to combine 2 tables, the problem is that when doing the "INNER JOIN" with a third it no longer recognizes the `cd.WorkDate`

error that I have is

> the multi-part identifier "cd.WorkDate" could not be found

```
UPDATE
    Emps
SET
    CanWork1 = CASE WHEN cd.WeekDay = 1 THEN 0 ELSE CanWork1 END,
    CanWork2 = CASE WHEN cd.WeekDay = 2 THEN 0 ELSE CanWork2 END,
    CanWork3 = CASE WHEN cd.WeekDay = 3 THEN 0 ELSE CanWork3 END,
    CanWork4 = CASE WHEN cd.WeekDay = 4 THEN 0 ELSE CanWork4 END,
    CanWork5 = CASE WHEN cd.WeekDay = 5 THEN 0 ELSE CanWork5 END,
    CanWork6 = CASE WHEN cd.WeekDay = 6 THEN 0 ELSE CanWork6 END,
    CanWork7 = CASE WHEN cd.WeekDay = 7 THEN 0 ELSE CanWork7 END
FROM
    #PS_EMPLOYEES AS Emps

    CROSS JOIN (SELECT WorkDate, WeekDay
    FROM #checkDays) AS cd

    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT EmployeeNumber, NewStatus
    FROM dbo.tblPAY_Employees_StatusHistory
    WHERE cd.WorkDate BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate) AS Stat
    ON Emps.EmployeeNumber = Stat.EmployeeNumber
WHERE
    IsNull(Stat.NewStatus,2) <> 1
```

Comment: If `#checkDays` has multiple rows, I don't think this query does what you intend -- even if you fix the syntax error.  You should ask a *new* question with sample data, desired results, a clear explanation of the logic -- and a fiddle usually helps too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting that error because you are accessing `cd.WorkDate` in your sub-query, If you take that where condition out of it, query should be good. Also your query should work without sub-query on `left join`. Try the following.

```
UPDATE
    Emps
SET
    CanWork1 = CASE WHEN cd.WeekDay = 1 THEN 0 ELSE CanWork1 END,
    CanWork2 = CASE WHEN cd.WeekDay = 2 THEN 0 ELSE CanWork2 END,
    CanWork3 = CASE WHEN cd.WeekDay = 3 THEN 0 ELSE CanWork3 END,
    CanWork4 = CASE WHEN cd.WeekDay = 4 THEN 0 ELSE CanWork4 END,
    CanWork5 = CASE WHEN cd.WeekDay = 5 THEN 0 ELSE CanWork5 END,
    CanWork6 = CASE WHEN cd.WeekDay = 6 THEN 0 ELSE CanWork6 END,
    CanWork7 = CASE WHEN cd.WeekDay = 7 THEN 0 ELSE CanWork7 END
FROM
    #PS_EMPLOYEES AS Emps

    CROSS JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            WorkDate, 
            WeekDay
        FROM #checkDays
    ) AS cd

    LEFT JOIN dbo.tblPAY_Employees_StatusHistory stat
    ON Emps.EmployeeNumber = Stat.EmployeeNumber
    WHERE cd.WorkDate BETWEEN stat.StartDate AND stat.EndDate
    AND IsNull(Stat.NewStatus,2) <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not obvious to me why you are using *any* subqueries in the `from` clause.  This is simpler and equivalent:

```
FROM #PS_EMPLOYEES Emps CROSS JOIN
     #checkDays cd LEFT JOIN
     dbo.tblPAY_Employees_StatusHistory stat
     ON cd.WorkDate BETWEEN stat.StartDate AND stat.EndDate AND
        Emps.EmployeeNumber = stat.EmployeeNumber
```

In SQL Server (and most databases) subqueries to select just a few columns are superfluous.  The optimizer ignores them -- actually the optimizer only processes the columns it needs from the table anyway.

As I note in the comment, though, this probably does not do what you really want.  In particular, if the `FROM` clause results in multiple rows for any row in `emps`, the update will be to a single arbitrary row.